# OpenBabel: how to get correct SMILES from Gaussian output?

Tags: software, cheminformatics

I would like to get the molecular structure as SMILES from Gaussian output files. OpenBabel seems to be the tool made for such tasks.
However, the structure is not always correct.

One example:

[image]

OpenBabel conversion Gaussian09 to SMILES (left):

```
N1(c2ccccc2)[C]2C=CC=CC2=[N]=C1c1ccccc1
```

SMILES generated by some drawing program (right):

```
C12=CC=CC=C1N(C3=CC=CC=C3)C(C4=CC=CC=C4)=N2
```

Is there a way (maybe a special option in OpenBabel which I missed) to directly get a correct output or to do some "postprocessing" to correct the SMILES afterward for example with RDKit or others?

**Update:**

One way to increase the yield of correct output seems to be the following.
If you convert the Gaussian output to InChI first, for the above example you'll get:

```
InChI=1S/C19H14N2/c1-3-9-15(10-4-1)19-20-17-13-7-8-14-18(17)21(19)16-11-5-2-6-12-16/h1-14H
```

Then, if you convert this InChI to SMILES, you'll get:

```
c1ccc(cc1)c1nc2ccccc2n1c1ccccc1
```

Which results in the right picture above.
However, even with this workaround some compounds, e.g. with `...C#N...` triple bonds are sometimes still incorrect.

I placed a [bug report](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/issues/2013) on GitHub. Let's see...

Any strategies, tips, and tricks to reliably and directly get a correct SMILES output are appreciated.

Comment: The left structure simply is wrong; that should probably be a bug report for open Babel. Do you have other examples? Also the smiles generated for the right side not apply aromaticity, so I wouldn't regard this as correct either.

Comment: Often structures containing Benzimidazoles are wrong... I will check a bug report for OpenBabel.

Comment: @Martin - マーチン♦, by the way, do you maybe know what exact section OpenBabel is extracting from the Gaussian output file (start/end keywords or headers)?. I found that if you convert first to InChI and then afterwards convert  these InChI to SMILES gives a higher "yield" of correct SMILES structures (but still not 100%).

Comment: I don't know, but I assume it's extracting the molecular structure, then probably forms internal coordinates, flattens the molecule, form a graph, translates it to smiles, canonicalise it. InChI just is probably less ambiguous. As for why it might yield 'correct (er)' results, I'm guessing the algorithm is different and more robust. In any case, a canonical smiles should have a 1:1 correspondence to InChI. But still, I'm guessing here... And open Babel is way too complex for me to understand or look into.

Comment: Do feel free to submit your findings as an answer! :)

Comment: @MelanieShebel well, sorry, no response at all on GitHub so far after 1.5 years... I have to test with the latest version...

Comment: @theozh I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: @theozh - At the moment, perceiving occurs via a set of heuristics, which certainly can make mistakes. It's impossible to debug either your post here or the bug report without a test file. We've made *many* changes to bond perception in both 3.0 releases and 3.1 releases. Without something to test, I can't say whether your particular cases are fixed or not.